# Why do most AST trees use classes instead of vectors

Tags: programming-languages, implementations

I've noticed that most AST tree implementations use classes for nodes instead of something like a vector. I want to ask, why do most people use classes? Are there issues to using vectors to make AST trees?

Comment: Vector of what?

Comment: Which implementation of vector isn't a class?

Comment: @Caleth: All vectors in languages that don't have classes, for example.

Comment: There's plenty of languages that don't even have classes which nonetheless have plenty of parsers written in them using ASTs. Clearly, those ASTs do not use classes. I question your premise. E.g. ML is a language that was specifically designed for being easy to implement other languages in (ML stands for "meta language"), and in ML (and similar languages), ASTs are typically modeled using Algebraic Types, not classes.

Comment: It's just a matter of expressiveness, which lets you achieve goals such as easy to write, easy to get working, easy to ensure correctness, easy to read, easy to modify as the language (or other requirements) change (the relative importance of each of those goals depends on the particular use case.  Plenty of ASTs were written - still are! - in plain LISP (without the object system).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to the existing answer, the classes (or algebraic types) represent the "node of the tree". Or rather, they represent the *kind of node* in the tree.

Being able to have more than one type of a node means that language implementors can allow for lots of variety. That means a tree's definition can be defined recursively with something like:

```
expr := Func(expr) | Num
```

A user's program can be:

- a number : `7`
- a function on a number: `f(7)`
- a function on a function on a number: `f(g(7))`
- etc.

Any part of the compiler or interpreter that walks the tree simply needs to implement the `expr` as being either a function or a number. So for classes, that can be done with inheritance and polymorphism; for algebraic types, that means pattern matching.

Now consider your alternative proposal: vectors mean that the *kind of node* must be homogeneous. No way for an expression to be either a function or number.

Comment: So basically, allowing programs to have multiple combinations of nodes without needing too much work?

Comment: @StandingPadAnimations Yeah, the main issue is heterogeneous selection: a recursive expression can have many variations, so we need something that represents variation.

Answer (score 4):

And what do you put in the vectors? Since it is a tree, you need to model depth. In languages with declarative types, that means a `vector<vector<vector<vector`… infinitely which isn’t actually denotable. Hence the recursive class.

Comment: Ahh. I didn't really think about depth. Thanks for the answer!